# How does python for .Net work?

Tags: c#, python, .net, mono, python.net

I've read [pythonnet](http://pythonnet.github.io/) project for integrating cpython and C#. The guide refers:

> Note that this package does not implement Python as a first-class CLR
>   language - it does not produce managed code (IL) from Python code.
>   Rather, it is an integration of the CPython engine with the .NET or
>   Mono runtime.This approach allows you to use CLR services and continue to use existing Python code and C-API extensions while maintaining native execution speeds for Python code.

Not to talk about IronPython, I just want to know how pythonnet work. If I have managed dlls writen in C# (I suppose they are in intermediate-language?). Does pythonnet somehow call a CLR service and make the managed code running under CLR?

CPython is a scripting language as far as I know, then it goes weird when a single python process could run under both python interpreter and CLR.
If the managed code is not controlled by the interpreter, does it mean that the execution speed can be faster than the original python scripts?
Specifically, Can someone provide me a clue about the workflow of pythonnet?

Comment: can you be more specific about your goal with pythonnet? pythonnet is just interop bridge between CPython and CLR runtimes.

Comment: @denfromufa I have a driver writen as C# library , .NET 4.6. And I want to make it work on python. Events and async are used.

Comment: Just post your issue with this code, async could be problem, events not sure.

Comment: Actually the code works, I just want to know its mechanism. i.e the performance depends on python interpreter or .NET runtime?

Comment: @denfromufa If pythonnet runs .net codes in a different section (say an individual CLR or .NET runtime), does it mean that the C# part(in dll) would not be limited by python GIL for multi-threading performance?

Comment: Yes, you can release GIL on C# code as long as it does not touch the Python runtime in those regions.

Comment: @denfromufa how can I release GIL for C# calls from python?

Comment: @irriss you cannot release GIL in pure python, only in Python C-API, e.g. Cython.